# Cannot access other machines on remote network with OpenVPN

Tags: windows, azure, openvpn

I am trying to set up OpenVPN so that I can access machines inside an Azure subnet from my pc which is outside Azure.

I have successfully installed OpenVPN on both server (Windows Server 2019) and pc (Windows 10) using the instructions here: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Easy_Windows_Guide?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=pmd_889e3e419b8b865ffd4da6e493bef6df0782273e-1629275604-0-gqNtZGzNAfijcnBszQgi, and I can successfully connect from client to server, however, I cannot connect to any other machine on the Azure subnet upon which the server is sitting.

The server and the other machines I want to connect to are on a 10.0.0.0 subnet, and the VPN is coming up on the 10.8.0.0 network as I would expect from the examples.

I have enabled IP routing on the server as recommended in the OpenVPN FAQ but this has not fixed the issue.

I have also added a 'push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0"' line to the server config, and I can see from the client log (and the client routing table) that this has been executed, but I am still unable to connect to other machines in the subnet.

I was looking into using Tap instead of Tun, but when I dug into at what was actually being used, it looks as if as if both ends are using the Tap adaptor anyway, even though I have specified 'dev tun' in both the client and the server configs.

I have had bit of a trawl but can't find anything about the Tap adaptor when the Tun adaptor has been configured, so that is a bit of a mystery.

The only other thing that I have read is that it might be necessary to set up a route back to the OpenVPN subnet on the gateway server for 10.0.0.0, but that's not a server I control as it's part of the Azure infrastructure.

What do I have to do to get access to other machines on the 10.0.0.0 subnet?  And why is the Tap adaptor being selected despite the config specifying the Tun adaptor ?

Answer (score 0):

I made a number of other changes before I finally got it sorted out - I do not know if they were all necessary but in addition to the above:

- I changed 'dev tun' to 'dev tap' in the server and client configs.
- I followed the instructions here [NAT-hack](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/NatHack) to add NAT to the server.
- And finally, I added 'route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.1' to the
  server config file.